# How do I use file_get_contents() when the filename contains a single quote?

Tags: php, single-quotes

I have to read the contents of a file with a single quote (`'`) in the file name. I have no influence on the file name, so renaming is not an option. Unfortunately, simply escaping it doesn't work, as in:

```
    $myFile = 'John\\\'s file';
    $text = file_get_contents($myFile);
```

What would be the correct way to access this file in PHP 5 on a Linux system?

Comment: tried `$myFile = "John's file";` ?

Comment: Actually, that was just example code. In the real code, the filename is read as as string out of another file, so that's not the issue. Just assume `$myFile` is a string containing a single quote.

Comment: i use ubuntu too and i have tried this `$myFile = "John's file";  print file_get_contents($myFile);` code now, it works.

Comment: Indeed, not escaping the string at all worked. I had tried that before, but it seems, back then, it failed for another reason. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to double-escape your string:

```
$myFile = 'John\'s file'; // This works fine.
$text = file_get_contents($myFile);
```

I've just tried a similar command on my terminal:

```
php -r "chdir('te\'st');"
```

It works.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. @eugen also pointed this out in his comments.